# Como puedo clonar una base datos SQL Server completa

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

necesito generar pruebas en mi base de datos para resolver algunos problemas, por lo que requiero clonar, copiar etc mi base de datos SQL Server completa, para en esta base clonada pueda cambiar, deshacer, modificar los datos para generar mis pruebas. Me podrían apoyar con soluciones para ello.

Comment: El camino fácil: [backup y restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento es bastante sencillo.
Si estás utilizando SQL Server Managment, solamente debes seleccionar la base de datos que deseas clonar (en este caso, haremos el *backup* de la base, que es con lo que te referís a clonar).

2. Se te ha de abrir un menú contextual, selecciona la opción *Task* o *Tareas*.
3. En este submenú, selecciona *Backup* o *Copia de Seguridad*.
4. Inmediatamente se abre una ventana, aquí verás una opción que dice **Tipo de respaldo** o **Backup type**, selecciona la opción que diga *Full* o *Total*.
5. En la parte inferior deberás específicar en qué parte quieres que se guarde el archivo .bak (que es el que contiene la estructura y los datos).
6. Esperas unos momento y la copia estará lista.
7. Luego, te dirigís a donde querás restaurar tu base "clonada" (tu ambiente de pruebas, supongo), en la sección "Base de datos" y ahí selecciona la opción "Restaurar base de datos".
8. Inmediatamente, selecciona, en el apartado del origen, la opción "Dispositivo" y exploras hasta encontrar el archivo .bak.
9. Seleccionas el archivo bak, le das aceptar y por último aceptas para restaurar tu base de datos.

*Crear .bak*
https://help.bizagi.com/bpm-suite/es/index.html?studio_backupsql.htm

*Restaurar .bak*
https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/05/25/importar-archivo-bak-base-de-datos-sql-server/

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esto si tienes una versión de posterior a SQL Server 2014:

```sql
DBCC CLONEDATABASE (nombreDbOriginal, nombreDbClonada)
```

Esto te dará una base de datos de solo lectura, para cambiar esto en la nueva base de datos, dale clic derecho y sigue esta ruta:

`Propiedades > Opciones > Estado (busca entre las opciones) > Base de datos solo lectura > False`

> Solo para que se entienda, el backup no es necesario y no es recomendable. Los backups sirven para proveer una solución (de varias que existen) de protección de los datos ante cualquier eventualidad, su función no es clonar.